# Importing Dependent DLLs in a PowerShell Script

Tags: c#, powershell, dll, nuget

**Problem Statement:**

Optimal way of importing dependent DLLs in PowerShell script.

**Explanation:**

I have a DLL, namely a.dll which has almost 10 dependencies on b.dll, c.dll,.... When I import the a.dll from the Nuget Package A in a PowerShell script then as the Dependent DLLs are not present in the same Directory it throws an error. I only have the DLLs in Nuget packages. The packages as usual will be in the

```
├── Nuget-A
│   ├── 1.0
|   |    |── a.dll
│   
├── Nuget-B
│   ├── 2.0
|   |    |── b.dll
```

In the PoweShell script I will import the a.dll,

> Import-Module "Nuget-A/1.0/a.dll"

This throws me an error so I do the following

> Import-Module "Nuget-B/2.0/b.dll" 
> Import-Module "Nuget-A/1.0/a.dll"

In the same way I have to do for the 10 DLLs.

What is the optimal way of handling the scenario? I am open to any other approaches too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not terribly experienced with PowerShell, but I expect that if all the assemblies were in the same directory, then when you import `a.dll`, it will automatically find the references, such as `b.dll`. That's how the .NET runtime loads assemblies, more or less, regardless of PowerShell, a console app, web app, and so on.

Therefore, instead of creating a package `A` that contains only `a.dll` and a dependency on package `B`, have package `A` not have any dependencies, and contain all 10 dlls in it.

There are a few ways to achieve that. One is to re-use csproj's `PackAsTool`. It publishes the project (using the equivalent of `dotnet publish`), and then packs everything in the publish folder. Since it's designed to pack console apps so that they can later be installed via `dotnet tool install`, you might have to do some hackery to get it to work. Another way is to run `dotnet publish`, then get nuget.exe from nuget.org/downloads, and cd to the publish directory run `nuget.exe spec` to create a template `.nuspec` file, edit that nuspec with all the metadata you want, then run `nuget.exe pack`. It will pack all the files in the directory into a nupkg. There are other ways too, for example try nugetizer, a community created tool, but this question is about how to solve referenced assembly loading, not how to pack, so I'll leave it at that. My point is that when you have a package that contains a PowerShell cmdlet, you shouldn't need to worry about loading all the dependencies in the powershell script/environvment using the package, so make sure the package is "self contained". It shifts the burden from consuming time to packing time, but at packing time all the dependencies are known, so it's an easier problem to solve.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks a lot!